# Different equation with bounded condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

$$y' = 2x(π+y)$$ 
$y$ being bounded when $x\to + ∞$

There is a singular solution $~y = -π~$ and it was the answer.

But general solution $y = ce^{x^2} - π$ ;$(|c| = e^{c})$ and $~c~$ must not be $~0~$.

$y - π = 0 = ce^{x^2}$ then $~c = 0~$?  why $~c~$  can be $~0~$ in this case?

And how do you know $~y = -π~$  satisfy the bounded condition?

Comment: Why must $c$ not be zero?

Comment: Because $$c =  e^{c1} $$ c1 is real number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'-2xy=2x\pi$$
$$IF=e^{-x^2}$$

$$\int d(ye^{-x^2})=2\pi\int xe^{-x^2}dx+C $$
$$ye^{-x^2}=-2\pi(\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2})+C \tag{1}$$
as $x\rightarrow \infty$ $C\rightarrow0$ 
$$y=-\pi$$

Hope it solved it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Put $z=y+\pi $. then
$$\frac {z'}{z}=2x $$
and

$$z=\lambda e^{x^2} $$

$$y(x)=\lambda e^{x^2}-\pi $$

if $\lambda\neq 0$ then

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}y (x)=\infty $$
but $y $ is bounded, thus
$\lambda=0$ and
$$y (x)=-\pi $$
is the only bounded solution.

Comment: $\lambda = e^{c} $ c is real number, right?  Why it can be zero?